# Composer RunimeException on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, composer-php, behat

I'm newbie in composer and was trying to install behat 3.0.6 via composer but when I executed this command inside my project directory:

1) composer require behat/behat='~3.0.6'

The next problem appear on my terminal:

2)  [RuntimeException]
 Could not read C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
 file_get_contents(C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin): failed to open stream:
  Permission denied

3) Then I ran the command diagnose, that was the result:

**Checking platform settings: FAIL**

The xdebug extension is loaded, this can slow down Composer a little.
Disabling it when using Composer is recommended, but should not cause issues beyond slowness.
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: OK

Notes: I have installed composer following the oficial guide: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#using-the-installer

Any idea?
Thanks!